# "The job interview went well" vs. "the job interview went off well"

Tags: difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *the job interview went well* and *the job interview went off well*? For example:

> Person A: So, how did the job interview go?
>
> Person B: It **went well**./ It **went off** **well**.

Comment: 'Went off well' is casual or conversational; 'went well' is more standard and formal.

Comment: **Went off well** is more likely to be used of an event than a lengthy project. Crowds turned out for the fete, which went off well in ideal weather. The tests on volunteers went well and team is hopeful of finding a vaccine.

Comment: Rnald Sole: Thanks for the comment! So in my case I use "went off" as a job intervew is an event, right?

Comment: Some people would be perfectly happy to say *the interview went **down** well*. Possibly *Americans* (AAVE?) in particular, who are more likely to ask *What's going **down**?* where I'd say *What's going **on**?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, "**It went well**" would be the more common answer. "It went off well" may be common in some regional dialects, but I haven't encountered it in areas I have travelled to or lived in.

As Ronald Sole said, the second option is more likely to be used for events (although it is still less common than "it went well"). However, I believe he meant the specific type of event that is organized for a group of people (such as a birthday, a ceremony, or a conference) rather than simply any event. The reason for this use could be related to the saying "It went off without a hitch", which means that something went very smoothly and successfully.

"Went off without a hitch" would be a more natural choice in most regional dialects of English than "went off well", with the caveat that "went off without a hitch" implies a stronger level of success than "went well" and is more casual.